# Pandas - Get average value by day and month

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a Pandas dataframe in this format:

```
    record_date val
0   2019-01-01  0.417022
1   2019-02-01  0.720324
2   2019-03-01  0.000114
3   2019-04-01  0.302333
4   2019-05-01  0.146756
5   2019-06-01  0.092339
6   2019-07-01  0.186260
7   2019-08-01  0.345561
8   2019-09-01  0.396767
9   2019-10-01  0.538817
```

How do I add a new column daily_average_val which contains the average value of the val column over all years for the month and day combination?

for 1-1-2024, I want the average of all January 1sts in the dataframe
for 1-1-2025, I want the average of all January 1sts in the dataframe (same as 1-1-2019,1-1-2020,1-1-2021)
for 2-1-2025, I want the average of all February 1sts in the dataframe

Comment: You should provide an example that has more than one year (you don't need to show all months though) and please provide the matching expected output for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Set up a custom grouper and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['daily_average_val'] = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['record_date'])
                                        .dt.strftime('%m-%d'))
                             ['val'].transform('mean')
                          )
```

Or, if you have a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
df['daily_average_val'] = (df.groupby(df['record_date'].str[4:])
                             ['val'].transform('mean')
                          )
```

Output:

```
  record_date       val  daily_average_val
0  2019-01-01  0.417022           0.417022
1  2019-02-01  0.720324           0.720324
2  2019-03-01  0.000114           0.000114
3  2019-04-01  0.302333           0.302333
4  2019-05-01  0.146756           0.146756
5  2019-06-01  0.092339           0.092339
6  2019-07-01  0.186260           0.186260
7  2019-08-01  0.345561           0.345561
8  2019-09-01  0.396767           0.396767
9  2019-10-01  0.538817           0.538817
```

*NB. since you only have one year, the `daily_average_val` output is identical to `val`.*